# LabView: Pass value between while loops

Tags: parallel-processing, labview

I've got a vi with two infinite while loops.  The left loop continuously reads data from a device and plots it, the right loop calls a custom DLL and uses the output to drive another device.  The DLL call blocks for about a second, so the two loops are not syncronized*.  Now I'd like to use the momentary value from the first loop as an input to the DLL in the second.  I tried just connecting them - LabVIEW inserts terminals at the loop boundaries - but then the second loop doesn't run.  (If it matters, the data type is "dynamic data" - a voltage measurement).  How do I do it?

(* In fact, originally there was only one loop, and the graph only got updated between DLL calls, which was not satisfactory.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is standard behaviour, since the first loop hasn't finished the data at the output gate is not available for the next loop to start.

The fastest method to get data from one loop is by using a local variable:

1. Create an indicator for your data
2. Right click the terminal of the indicator, and select 'create\local variable'
3. Move the local variable to the right loop
4. Perhaps you need to change the loop from writing to reading (using the context menu)

There are several other ways to distribute your data, and locals might work for now, but you will want to move on if you scale to larger applications.
Other options are queues (lossless or non-lossless), or notifier, or global variables, and if you advance in LabVIEW you'll come up with your own schemes.

Comment: Thanks, local variables solved my problem. I had a control in the left loop that displayed my value anyway, and I added a variable associated with that to the other loop. (For posteriority: had to change it to "reading" from the context menu.) One small thing: I think the reason that the second loop didn't run was not that it was waiting for the first to finish - after all, both loops are infinite - but that it did not have any input node.

Comment: I'm sure that the second loop is waiting for the first one to finish.
You can use 'Execution Highlight' to see the code run in slow-mo.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a "Producer Consumer" loop.

There's a template that ships with LabVIEW(File >> New... >> VI >> From Template >> Design Patterns) that's a good starting point.

Also, more info here:

http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3023

http://zone.ni.com/wv/app/doc/p/id/wv-1295

PS - the reason the second loop doesn't run is because of a concept called "Data Flow". A node (your second loop) cannot run until all of it's inputs have been received, including the data from the first loop. A node (the first loop) doesn't output anything out of it, until it has finished execution, i.e., till the loop ends.

So essentially, your second loop wouldn't run until the first loop has run and finished looping.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to queue the output values, but I want to have both loops run each at their own speed, in parallel, and the second loop sample the current value from a node in the first. It's perfectly fine if some values produced by the first loop are skipped.

Comment: Do you want the second loop to run *only* after the first loop has outputed some value? 
Or do you want the second loop to run even if the first loop has not finished running (and outputing a value)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you might not like that extra indicator on your front panel, only to use its value via local variables. You could then use a global variable. You can find it under "Structures". This creates a new VI where you can drop different indicators or controls just for writing and reading data to/from them. You can drop this global variable VI into your block diagram to access the data. Then, you could use the same global variable VI and its values in other VIs as well, if needed.